# JQuery mousemove not restarting

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I am having is with `$('.someclass').on('mousemove', function() { do something });`.  So when I hover over a button it will dynamically add an element that will follow the mouse, once my counter reaches say 500, the new element is removed.  This all works fine however when hovering back over the button it doesn't work the second time.  Below is a code example.

Every time one hovers over the button a new dynamic element should be added and then removed after a set amount of mouse moves but it won't work the second hover.

```
$('.someClass').on('mouseover' function() { 

  $('.element').appendTo('body');

  $('body').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
    var mousey = e.pageY;
    $('.element').css({ top: mousey, left: mousex, position: 'absolute' });

    if (mouse_move >= 500) {
      ('.element').remove();
    }
    mouse_move++;

  });

});
```

Comment: Could you provide us with failing jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: You are talking about `.hover()` which is very very different from `.mouseover()`

Comment: At first guess, you select an element by class and append it to the body. After hitting 500 in counter you remove element. I assume that element no longer exists to append on the next mouseover.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace The element is recreated every mouseover.

Comment: @Mr.Wolf Yes I understand they are different but I switched to mouseover when .hover() was doing this, didn't fix the problem.  I am working on a jsfiddle right now

Comment: You never reset `mouse_move` so it's always `>=500` after the first time - so any time it gets re-added, it's immediately removed.

Comment: @user3338101 `.hover()` can accept 2 arguments. The first for mouse enters, the second for mouse leaves. Just like my answer below. Using the second argument to reset your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example. Not sure if this is what you want but I still stand by comment up above. I don't see you recreating that element on mouseover every time.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/6k70v3x3/

JS:

```
$('.someClass').on('mouseover', function () {
    doStuff();
});

function doStuff() {

    $('.someClass').off('mouseover');
    $('<div class="element"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var mouse_move = 0;

    $('body').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
        var mousey = e.pageY;
        $('.element').css({
            top: mousey,
            left: mousex,
            position: 'absolute'
        });

        if (mouse_move >= 500) {
            alert('removed');
            $('.element').remove();
            $('body').off('mousemove');
            $('.someClass').on('mouseover', function () {
                doStuff();
            });
        }
        mouse_move++;

    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.someClass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
.element {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help you fixed the issue.  I was forgetting to restart the `'mouseover'` and call my function again after `mouse_move >= 500`

Comment: @user3338101 happy to help! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Typo: I guess it is just a mistake of a `$` sign missing from the `remove()` statement.

Reset your counter and remove mousemove

Here is the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/uLo91hqb/3/

It should be like this:

```
mouse_move = 0;
$('.someClass').on('mouseover', function () {

    $('.element').appendTo('body');

    // Show the counter again
    // Purpose for >=0 is for fast mousemovement sometime 0 may not been recorded
    // It it quickly counts 3-4 .. You can see it in fiddle
    if (mouse_move >= 0) 
        $('.element').show();

    $('body').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20;
        var mousey = e.pageY;
        $('.element').css({
            top: mousey,
            left: mousex,
            position: 'absolute'
        });

        if (mouse_move >= 500) {
            // Remove mousemove from the body
            $('body').off('mousemove');
            // Reset counter
            mouse_move = 0;
            $('.element').hide();
        }
        mouse_move++;
        $('.counter').html(mouse_move);

    });

});
```

Comment: Has the same problem as OPs - doesn't come back after the first time it goes away. Having difficulty seeing what difference this code has with OPs other than obvious typo fix + showing the counter

Comment: Updated my answer. I misunderstood at first.

Answer (score 0):

From [the doc](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

`handlerIn`: A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.

`handlerOut`: A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.

Example:

```js
$('p').hover(function () {
  $(this).css('color', '#f00')
}, function () {
  $(this).css('color', '#000')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hover me</p>
```

You can follow my example to edit your js code.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your variable 'mouse_move' ever gets defined or reset.
Try:

```
$('.someClass').on('mouseover' function() { 
  var mouse_move = 0;
  ...
});
```